# An OR statement

Tags: excel

I'm attempting to combine these 2 statements with an OR statement.  The first is a number that has to be shortened by 3 digits to the left.  And the second is an alphanumeric statement that is 6 digits long.  I was thinking `=--(OR(MID(B2,4,7),MID(B2,1,7)))`.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Sorry you need to explain a bit better, I can't make sense of what you're trying to do ??  Can you show an example of what you have .. and what you want ?

Comment: In what sense  is a "number which needs to be shortened by 3 digits" a statement, and what does "an alphanumeric statement with 6 digits" even *mean*? Statements are not collections of digits. You can *coerce* all sorts of things to Booleans, but that doesn't mean that the things coerced are usefully described as statements.

Answer (score 0):

`=Concatenate(Right(text(B2,0),len(text(B2,0))-3),Left(text(B2,0),6))`

I had to take a big guess at what you were trying to achieve based on your question.